# OAuth2 - Call to undefined method Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId()

Tags: php, swift, laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen

I am using Lumen Api & [OAuth2-Server-Laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/) repo and iOS App on Swift.

I accessed the `token` in return of valid client and user credentials and stored it in the app. Now I am trying to exchange `token` with `user_id`.

I tried what I've found on [OAuth github repo's support](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/issues/235) for `getting user_id from access_token`

This is the error I am getting:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined method LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId() in /home/vagrant/LumenAPI/app/Http/Controllers/OAuthController.php on line 27`

I tried to use the `token` and receive `user_id` in return.

My Route in Lumen looks like:

```
$app->get('/me', 'OAuthController@token');
```

OAuthController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\Authorizer;

class OAuthController extends Controller
{

  private $authorizer;

  public function __construct(Authorizer $authorizer)
  {
      $this->authorizer = $authorizer;
  }

  public function token()
  {
    $user_id = $this->authorizer->getResourceOwnerId();
    return Response::json(['data'=> $user_id]);     //Line 27
  }
 }
```

I used this GET request on Swift:

```
func me(handler: (data: NSDictionary?, error: String?) -> Void)
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: "/me", relativeToURL: self.baseUrl)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        // The request is valid only if the access_token exists
        if let t = self.getAccessToken()  // valid
        {
            request.setValue("Bearer \(t)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            let taskInstance = DataTaskHandler()
            taskInstance.make(request, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
                if let res = result
                {
                    if let jsonDictionary = JSONParser(data: res).dictionary()
                    {
                            print(jsonDictionary)
                        handler(data: jsonDictionary, error: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            handler(data:nil, error: "The access token is not available")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuthController should be

```
class OAuthController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('oauth');
}

public function token(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
    return response()->json(['data'=> $user_id]);
}
```